# context.Variable.GetValueOrDefault<string>("var1") is not accessing in xslt policy

Tags: api, xslt, soap, azure-api-management, policy

I am working on modifying the input soap message using the Xslt policy.

I am using this policy twice so, my actual request is lost after executing the first time. During second time xslt was not able to find the actual request to perform operation.

So I tried to store the actual request Body to a variable and using the variable inside policy.

Variable creation:

```
<set-variable name="var1" value="@(context.Request.Body.As<string>())"/>
```

After creating the variable I am using the variable like below.

```
<xsl:variable name="req" select="context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("var1")/>
```

When I am using this it is throwing error '<' hexadecimal value 0x3c, is an invalid attribute character.

How to use apim variable inside xslt policy?

Answer (score 0):

[Parameter - Used to define variables used in the transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#XSLTransform)

So in your case it would be this node added inside `<xsl-transform>`:

```
<parameter name="req">@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault("var1",""))</parameter>
```

and then: